# Facebook like error. You failed to provide a valid list of administators.

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-insights

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to fix this error that i have. I am using godaddy's website tonight, and on my website I am trying to add the Facebook “like” button. But when i click it I get the following message:

> You failed to provide a valid list of administators. You need to
>   supply the administors using either a `fb:app_id` meta tag, or using a
>   `fb:admins` meta tag to specify a comma-delimited list of Facebook
>   users.

I then went to my Facebook page were I have a page for my bussiness. I went to "insights for your website" and  filled in the website name and linked with me.  got the meta tag, `<meta property="fb:admins" content="1349905809" />` and placed this on my website. I even had godaddy IT team place this tag on my root page, and several other location on my site. But when I the try to link insights with my website, I get this message:

> No admin data found at root webpage http://kanopyking.net/. Insights
>   requires admin data at this root webpage for the specified URL
>   (kanopyking.net)

Is this meta tag that FB is providing me correct?  why cant FB insights see my admin information on my page?

Answer (score 2):

If you have not added namespace for FB in the `<html></html>` tag of your webpage, you will need to do so.

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

To enable insites on my websites I use the `app_id` tag, not the `admin_id` tag.

Sample for a non domain root page:

```xml
<head>
   <title>Another Feed Javascript API</title>
   <meta property="og:title" content="Another Feed"/>
   <meta property="og:description" content="Another Feed Javascript API Test Page"/>
   <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
   <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $this_ogimage; ?>"/>
   <meta property="og:site_name" content="Another Feed"/>
   <meta property="og:url" content="http://ShawnsSpace.com/plugins/af.php"/>
   <meta property="fb:app_id" content="246061345438635"/>
</head>
```

For root pages "example.com" the `og:type` needs to be set to website or blog.

Comment: shawn, what is "namespace for facebook"? are you saying i need to copy and past that xmlns code that you have highlighted into my website?  you said you used the app_id tag, were do i find this tag? go easy on me please as im still learning all this programmming code.  thanks,

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
           xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
           xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <title>party rental</title>
        <meta content="party tent rental" property="og:title" />
        <meta content="website" property="og:type" />
        <meta content="http://www.kanopyking.net" property="og:url" />
        <meta property="og:image" />
        <meta content="kanopy king" property="og:site_name" />
        <meta content="1349905809" property="fb:admins" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>   is this correct?

Comment: can someone tell me how to post my HTML code? i would like to post it to see if it is correct. when i try to post it, it does not show up

Comment: how to post code in comment http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting
` code `
`<code></code>`

Comment: yes you need to declare namespace for facebook in your <html> tag.

Comment: you can goto my website and look at the source code for referrence if you need http://shawnsspace.com

Comment: <code><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
      <head>
        <title>party rental</title>
        <meta content="party rental" property="og:title" />
        <meta content="website" property="og:type" />
        <meta content="http://www.kanopyking.net" property="og:url" />
        <meta property="og:image" />
        <meta content="kanopy king" property="og:site_name" />
        <meta content="1349905809" property="fb:admins" />
            </head>
            <br />
    </body>
</html></code>

Comment: Mike that is correct, if your still have error, more og:admin and use og:app_id instead.

Answer (score 0):

On the page where you get the error message - there is an image right below it of a cutout of code. It says:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="xxx" />
```

I also added this in the html tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
```